# Server PC hangs, and then the client PCs hang as well, when playing CS 1.3 through LAN

Tags: technical-issues, counter-strike

I am currently using Counter Strike 1.3 and there are more than 4 players playing. We get connected through the `connect <<IP>>` command, but while playing the game, sometimes the PC hangs (the one we are using as a server) and when this happens, all of the PCs hang as well.

I have tried to use another PC as the server but there is still no change - it still hangs.

Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: Is this question about [Counter-Strike](http://store.steampowered.com/app/10/) or [Counter-Strike: Source](http://store.steampowered.com/app/240/)?

Answer (score 1):

I used to get these problems in my college when arranging CS 1.6 events. However, we got over these by making other PCs server or re-installing the game. This can happen due to a corrupted file too.
Try re-installing the game and checking your graphics drivers and also the Hub/Switch which you use, make sure enough bandwidth is allocated in the configuration. 
Mostly this happens either due to a bad connection medium or hardware.